# undefined reference to methods in ssl(openssl)

Tags: ssl, gcc

I'm Trying to compiling a simple socket code which uses SSL. I have installed latest version of openssl on Ubuntu 14.+ Version of OS. When I try to compile using the below command

```
gcc -o sslconnect testSSLConnect.c -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

I get the following error.

```
/tmp/ccRO7jY9.o: In function `main':
testSSLConnect.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
testSSLConnect.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `ERR_load_crypto_strings'
testSSLConnect.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
testSSLConnect.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
testSSLConnect.c:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `SSLv23_client_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think this looks like a linker problem which I'm unable to figure it out. Appreciate your help on this

Below is the message that i see when i run gcc with -v option

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/usr/local/lib' '-o' 'sslconnect' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu SSL_Client.c -quiet -dumpbase SSL_Client.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase SSL_Client -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccVABqoE.s
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/firmwaredev/Dev/yocto/build_etn-cgtqmx6/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include/
 /home/firmwaredev/Dev/yocto/build_etn-cgtqmx6/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include/openssl/
 .
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: dc75e0628c9356affcec059d0c81cc01
SSL_Client.c: In function ‘InitCTX’:
SSL_Client.c:68:12: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
     method = SSLv3_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
            ^
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/usr/local/lib' '-o' 'sslconnect' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccITCmac.o /tmp/ccVABqoE.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/firmwaredev/Dev/yocto/build_etn-cgtqmx6/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/home/firmwaredev/Dev/yocto/build_etn-cgtqmx6/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/:./:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/usr/local/lib' '-o' 'sslconnect' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o sslconnect /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/firmwaredev/Dev/yocto/build_etn-cgtqmx6/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/home/firmwaredev/Dev/yocto/build_etn-cgtqmx6/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib -L. -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. /tmp/ccITCmac.o -lcrypto -lssl -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/ccITCmac.o: In function `InitCTX':
SSL_Client.c:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
SSL_Client.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
SSL_Client.c:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `SSLv3_client_method'
/tmp/ccITCmac.o: In function `main':
SSL_Client.c:(.text+0x32f): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please share more information: `gcc -v` output, and testSSLConnect.c code (minimal verifiable example). Your description of build seems correct, everything shall work.

Comment: Hi my testSSLConnect uses openssl functions to make SSL connection over tcp the undefined reference error tells the functions that i'm using

Comment: Why just not provide MCVE and compiler information? I have good guess why you have problems, but I need to check before answer.

Comment: Updated with compile messages

Comment: From linker line in gcc output, I can see, that you are using: `-lcrypto -lssl` in that order, not in order, specified in question body.

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov : I tried both the orders still i get the same error log